# How to split more than one comma separated column as a separate row in SQL using CROSS APPLY

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, cross-apply

I have one table having following rows

| Name | Phones | Courses |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 123, 456 | HTML, Java |
| XYZ | 321, 654 | PHP, CSS |

now I want to write a SELECT query to get these comma separated Phone and Courses as a separate row. By using this SELECT query I yield results till Phone column but stuck at 2nd column. Select query is

```
SELECT 
    Name, 
    value phone,
    courses
FROM 
    tblName 
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(phones, ',');
```

This query shows me following results:

| Name | Phones | Courses |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 123 | HTML, Java |
| ABC | 456 | HTML, Java |
| XYZ | 321 | PHP, CSS |
| XYZ | 654 | PHP, CSS |

Please help me to split Courses column as like Phones and want to yield following results:

| Name | Phones | Courses |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 123 | HTML |
| ABC | 456 | HTML |
| ABC | 123 | Java |
| ABC | 456 | Java |
| XYZ | 321 | PHP |
| XYZ | 654 | PHP |
| XYZ | 321 | CSS |
| XYZ | 654 | CSS |

Comment: You've tagged MYSQL however `cross apply`  and `string_split` is *SQL Server*

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: *By using this SELECT query I yield results till Phone column but stuck at 2nd column.* It's obvious that you need in 2 CROSS APPLY.

Comment: I updated the tags to fit the question better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since - according to your description - you used `CROSS APPLY` and your query was successfully executed, this means you are using a SQL Server DB, not MY SQL. You can do two `CROSS APPLY` to get your expected result. This will produce exactly the outcome you have shown in your question:

```
SELECT name, phone, value courses FROM
(SELECT name, value phone, courses 
FROM tblName CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(phones, ',')) x
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(courses, ',')
ORDER BY name, courses, phone;
```

You can verify this here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e2dd46330aa3a52390d75ed7c338ea27)

But this is very risky and you really should avoid such comma-separated contents in one column. I highly recommend to create separate columns for the different values in future.

Answer (score 1):

Well I found the solution myself.
here is the working query:

```
SELECT 
    t1.name,
    t1.phone,
    value course
FROM
    (SELECT 
        first_name, 
        value phone,
        courses
    FROM 
        tblName 
        CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(phones, ',')) t1
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(t1.courses, ',');
```

Thanks everyone.